# p4 triggers for specific file extensions not working?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, perforce

I would like to run a script when a *.cpp file's submitted. But when I changed the p4 triggers to specify the file extension, it stopped working?

this command works:

`bugcheck1 change-submit //PlayPen/... /mnt/scripts/jenkins-trigger.sh`

This command doesn't work:

`bugcheck1 change-submit //PlayPen/*.cpp /mnt/scripts/jenkins-trigger.sh`

Answer (score 2):

The `*` operator doesn't match any path segment containing `/` -- in other words, it only matches at a single directory level.

This means that the path `//PlayPen/*.cpp` will only match `.cpp` files that are at the root of the `//PlayPen` depot:

```
//PlayPen/*.cpp
//PlayPen/foo.cpp     -> matches  ('*' = 'foo')
//PlayPen/bar/foo.cpp -> does not match
//Widget/foo.cpp      -> does not match
```

If you want to match all `.cpp` files anywhere in the depot, you want the `...` wildcard:

```
//PlayPen/....cpp
//PlayPen/foo.cpp     -> matches  ('...' = 'foo')
//PlayPen/bar/foo.cpp -> matches  ('...' = 'bar/foo')
//Widget/foo.cpp      -> does not match
```

If you want to match all `.cpp` files anywhere in *any* depot, drop the `PlayPen` part:

```
//....cpp
//PlayPen/foo.cpp     -> matches  ('...' = 'PlayPen/foo')
//PlayPen/bar/foo.cpp -> matches  ('...' = 'PlayPen/bar/foo')
//Widget/foo.cpp      -> matches  ('...' = 'Widget/foo')
```

To see what patterns match what files, try using them with the `p4 files` command:

```
p4 files //PlayPen/*.cpp
p4 files //PlayPen/....cpp
```